WSL can't run any exe files after I added options = "metadata,umask=022,fmask=111" to wsl config
WSL can't run any exe files after I added options = "metadata,umask=022,fmask=111" to wsl config.
I can chmod some exe files +x to and make them run but some I can't. I'm currently trying to open file with chrome, but I would like a general solution so I can run all exe files.
➜  simple_web git:(main) ✗ strace -o strace_log.txt wslview https://www.google.com
/usr/bin/wslview: line 216: /mnt/c/Windows/System32/reg.exe: Permission denied
/usr/bin/wslview: line 149: /mnt/c/Windows/System32/chcp.com: Permission denied
/usr/bin/wslview: line 156: /mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe: Permission denied
/usr/bin/wslview: line 149: /mnt/c/Windows/System32/chcp.com: Permission denied 


"… after I added … to wsl config" – The obvious fix is to revert this change. If you tell us what you were trying to achieve by making the change in the first place, maybe we will be able to give you a solution that does this and allows you to run exe files, or we will explain why you cannot have both (if this is the case).

Your fmask is configured exactly the way you wanted to block all access to all files by default so the behavior you describe is expected.

I was trying to share windows ssh keys. I simplify forgot to mention it. @KamilMaciorowski

Try changing fmask to 000 which is the default option.
Setting fmask to 111 restricts the execute permission for files.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#automount-options.
